# Show that the function has a root in (0,1)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let  be a polynomial given by

$$f(x)=x^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-a_{n-2}x^{n-2}-…-a_1x-a_0$$

If $_0 + _1 + ⋯ + _{−1} < 1$ and $_0 > 0,$ show that  has a root in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: $f(0)<0, f(1)>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_0>0$ implies that $f(0)=-a_0<0$, and $a_0+a_1+...+a_{n-1}<1$ implies that $f(1)=1-(a_0+a_1+...+a_{n-1})>1-1=0$, since all the powers of $x$ will equal 1 at that point.

So we have $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$, and applying the Intermediate Value Theorem shows that there must exist $x\in(0,1)$ for which $f(x)=0$, the result!